# Is there a way to automaically migrate stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, left-join, database-migration

We're migrationg from an old version of MS SQL Server to a much more recent version. The trouble is, we have too many equally old stored procedures that won't run in the new version, in particular, many use the "*=" notation instead of "LEFT JOIN" or RIGHT JOIN. Upgrading them on-hand would be extremely error-prone and time consuming (just one of the databases I'm in charge of has 900+ SP, and I've yet to check the other four!), so I'm wondering if there's any software out there that can aupgrade all these procedures. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the target version of SQL server, but I believe all of the recent version have a corresponding SQL Upgrade Advisor. I believe this tool will be useful as it will identify all of the places you use the obsolete syntax.

Assuming you only have server-side code (and no dynamic sql) this would be useful.

However, I don't think you will find any tool that can do this automatically for all cases -- the old style syntax was at times ambiguous and there are other possible problems.

You might find this [article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2013/03/02/using-the-query-designer-to-convert-non-ansi-joins-to-ansi.aspx) useful though as it shows how you can use SMSS to convert an old-style join. It is not perfect, and it does not always yield the highest performance equivalent join, but it may be better than nothing.

I never used the old-style joins myself on MS as my first version of MS-SQL was 7.0.